# two webservers on two different machines on the same domain

Tags: apache, subdomain

let's say i have a website
example.com
i have 2 servers, both running apache2.
on server1 i have a an apache2 web server configured with port 443 accessible through
https://example.com
i have another web server running on port 3456 with configured with reverse proxy and alias that is accessible through https://site1.example.com
configuration for this next site is as follows

```
        <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

            ServerName site1.example.com

            ProxyPass / http://localhost:3456/
            ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3456/

            Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

            ServerAlias site1.example.com
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1.example.com/fullchain.pem
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/site1.example.com/privkey.pem
    </VirtualHost>
```

site1 works fine.
Finally i have a third web server running on server2 port 80. I want to access it with https://site2.example.com What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: since it is running on port 80 (http) you will never be able to access it as https://

Comment: the configuration for https should be configured on server1 which is the one that i can access from https://example.com, https://site2.example.com configuration should also be on server1, instead pointing to server2 from there. I tried a configuration like ProxyPass / http://server2:80/ ProxyPassReverse / http://server2:80/ and it works with the first page, but it broke JQuerry and if i open any page from the website on server2 is cannot find that.